# R - convert a string of repeat amino acids from e.g. NNNN to (N4)

Tags: r, regex

I am computing haplotypes from multiple sequence alignments and am getting stretches of repeats such as RNNNNNNNT and RNNNT. There are many variations, making it hard to make sense of the data.

The data is listed as below and am I'm interested in generating the column **haplotypes_2** based on **haplotypes_1** as indicated:

```
hap_code    haplotypes_1          haplotypes_2
  1    SKNNNRNNNNNKNNNNNNNKF    SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF
  2    SKNNNNNNNNNKNNNNNNNNKF   SK(N9)K(N8)KF
  3    SKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKF     SK(N16)KF
```

Comment: I would just use a for loop, a variable storing the previously seen character, and a count variable which increments if the current char is the same as the previous char.

Comment: For future reference, this transformation is called [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: Check out the `rle()` function in base R.  It doesn't do what you want, since it works on elements of a vector instead of characters in a string, but you could put together your own function based on it:  convert the string to a vector (maybe using `strsplit`), use `rle` to get the encoding, then convert back to a string in the format you want.

Comment: Hi @user2554330, let me give it a try...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost exactly the same as @d.b, but converted to a couple functions so it's reusable and reader-friendly:

```
abbreviate_letters <- function(type_letters) {
  runs <- rle(type_letters)
  run_codes <- ifelse(
    runs[["lengths"]] == 1,
    yes = runs[["values"]],
    no  = paste0("(", runs[["values"]], runs[["lengths"]], ")")
  )
  paste0(run_codes, collapse = "")
}


condense_haplotype <- function(haplotype_long) {
  split_terms <- strsplit(haplotype_long, split = "")
  vapply(
    X         = split_terms,
    FUN       = abbreviate_letters,
    FUN.VALUE = character(1)
  )
}


haplotypes <- c(
  "SKNNNRNNNNNKNNNNNNNKF",
  "SKNNNNNNNNNKNNNNNNNNKF",
  "SKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKF"
)

condense_haplotype(haplotypes)
# [1] "SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF" "SK(N9)K(N8)KF"      "SK(N16)KF"
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `stringr` and a custom function:

```
library(stringr)

replace_string <- function(x) {
  sprintf("(%s%i)", str_sub(x, end = 1L), str_length(x))
}

df1$hapnew <- str_replace_all(df1$haplotypes_1, "N+", replace_string)

  hap_code           haplotypes_1       haplotypes_2             hapnew
1        1  SKNNNRNNNNNKNNNNNNNKF SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF
2        2 SKNNNNNNNNNKNNNNNNNNKF      SK(N9)K(N8)KF      SK(N9)K(N8)KF
3        3   SKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKF          SK(N16)KF          SK(N16)KF
```

Comment: Dear @manotheshark, I got the following error: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'haplotypes_1'.

Comment: @K.Wamae that's the column name from the sample data in the question.  You'll have to change the `data.frame` or column name as needed to how your data is structured.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = c("SKNNNRNNNNNKNNNNNNNKF", "SKNNNNNNNNNKNNNNNNNNKF", "SKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKF")
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(mystr)
    with(rle(mystr),
         paste(paste0(ifelse(lengths > 1, paste0("(",values), values),
                      ifelse(lengths > 1, paste0(lengths,")"), ""),
                      collapse = ""))))
#[1] "SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF" "SK(N9)K(N8)KF"      "SK(N16)KF"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `gsubfn` and `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("N+", ~paste0("(", substr(x, 1, 1), str_count(x), ")"), df1$haplotypes_1)
#[1] "SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF" "SK(N9)K(N8)KF"      "SK(N16)KF"
```

---

Or as @G.Grothendieck suggested, the `str_count` can be replaced with `nchar`

```
gsubfn("N+", ~sprintf("(%0.1s%d)", x, nchar(x)), df1$haplotypes_1) 
#[1] "SK(N3)R(N5)K(N7)KF" "SK(N9)K(N8)KF"      "SK(N16)KF"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prev <- ""
count <- 1
output <- ""
for (character in string) {
  if (character==prev) {
    count <- count + 1
  }
  else {
    if (count > 1) {
      output <- output + prev + toString(count)
    }
    else {
      output <- output + prev
    }
  }
  prev <- character
}
```

This alludes to my comment, there may be a problem hiding in this but the gist is there.

Comment: Dear @Dylan, I tested it like this

Comment: prev <- "N"
count <- 1
output <- ""
for (character in "SNNNNNNTNNNNK") {
  if (character==prev) {
    count <- count + 1
  }
  else {
    if (count > 1) {
      output <- output + prev + toString(count)
    }
    else {
      output <- output + prev
    }
  }
  prev <- character
}

Comment: Got the following error: Error in output + prev : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @K.Wamae yes it should be `paste`, not added, I just wrote a generic pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest another one:

```
df <- data.frame(haplotypes_1 = c("SKNNNRNNNNNKNNNNNNNKF", 
                                  "SKNNNNNNNNNKNNNNNNNNKF", 
                                  "SKNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNKF"))
df$haplotypes_2 <- sapply(df$haplotypes_1, function(q){
  x <- rle(strsplit(as.character(q), "N")[[1]])
  res <- rep("", length(x$lengths))
  res[x$lengths != 1] <- paste("(N", x$lengths[x$lengths != 1], ")", sep="")
  res[x$lengths == 1] <- x$values[x$values != ""]
  paste(res, collapse = "")
})
```

Comment: Thank you, @storaged, I however, added a closing round bracket at the end of the code to for it to run, would you mind making that edit. I have tried and it says that edits must be 6 characters long.

Comment: Hi @storaged, I needed to re-use this code in another project and I noticed that whenever a character appears before the repeated string, the code counts one less match..e.g. SNNN would be condensed into S(N2) instead of S(N3). Kindly assist